# how to hide a second button and reveal it only when first button pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

there are two buttons, which means there are 2 actions. How would i hide the second button and only reveal it after the first is pressed?

code:

```
- (IBAction)btnFirst:(id)sender {
 //this button should reveal the button bellow called btnSecond

    }
    else{


    }
   }
}

- (IBAction)btnSecond:(id)sender {


    }
    else{


    }
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *boxOne;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *boxTwo;
```

Comment: This isn't a question, but a fill-in the blanks puzzle.

Comment: @Abizern Nice analogy, but if it was a fill in the blanks puzzle, then tell me this: how come, I gain so much knowledge from the help that was given. If you want to criticise another mans thirst for knowledge become a lawyer, or answer the question. The Power of the World is Online! Viva la Web!

Comment: Actually the power of programming is knowledge. The ability to learn, and the ability to find one's own solutions. You might think you're learning, but I'm sorry to say it seems like you are just putting together bits of code you find on the web.

Comment: @Abizern I'm learning, and I'm building with example, I've gone over all the code that people help me with - but most importantly I'm learning, Your opinion is yours, and I will accept it, but I will not believe it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your 'viewDidLoad`....

```
self.boxTwo.hidden = YES;
```

then in your `IBAction`

```
- (IBAction)btnFirst:(id)sender {
    self.boxTwo.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that in your view, boxOne is above boxTwo, then you could use this :

```
- (IBAction)btnFirst:(id)sender {
       self.boxOne.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden property for hiding button. use boxTwo.hidden = YES; in the second button action method

```
 - (IBAction)btnFirst:(id)sender {


    self.boxTwo.hidden = NO;

        }
```

Comment: Hi, one question, just want to know if I'm understanding it correctly, The OP wants to reveal button `boxTwo` on the the first action, no? This makes the second button hidden..

Comment: Dude its only a logic by this op can understand how can he hide buttons in objective c

Comment: But, IMHO it has to be `self.boxTwo.hidden = NO;` in your answer.. The OP wants to reveal a hidden button, not hide it. Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: ohhh sorry i updated my answer....you are correct here i gave only idea using hidden property of the button,op can show and hide button by using hidden property according to his requirements. thanks for correcting my mistake @iSeeker

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, select the `boxTwo` button and go to Attributes inspector(the one in the middle) at the right pane, then in `view` category make the checkbox that says `hidden` as checked. Then do this:

```
- (IBAction)btnFirst:(id)sender {
   self.boxTwo.hidden = NO;
}
```